# Prove that A compact hausdorff space is generated by a weak topology of C(X,R)

Tags: general-topology

Prove that A compact hausdorff space is a weak topology generated by 
C(X,R) ,by using C(X,R) separates points of X i.e for x not equal to y there exists a function f in C(X,R) s.t f(x) not equal to f(y), Where 
C(X,R)is the set of all continuous real valued function from X to R.

Comment: Here the problem is I can separate only two points for a particular function. There is no guarantee that it will separates other points or not. So how to create a basis element in the open set containing x by weak topology?

Comment: I'm not sure what the word "generated" means in the sentence "A compact Hausdorff space is generated by a weak topology of $C(X,R)$".

Comment: See the definition of weak topology.

Comment: "Weak topology" was not the part of the sentence that I did not understand.  Your question, as you wrote it, is meaningless.

Comment: No it is not. Weak topology is a topology generated by functions which is C(X,R). If it is still not clear then see introduction to topology by Simmons. Complete regular spaces and normal spaces P no 134. Q no 3

Comment: user152715:  @PaulSiegel's complaint is that the phrase "a compact hausdorff space *is* [emphasis added] a weak topology generated by ..." doesn't make sense.  One reason for this is that a *space* is not a *topology*.   In fact, it's not quite clear what you're asking.  Are you asking about the topology on $X$ induced by embedding it into the dual space of $C(X,R)$, this dual space being given its weak topology?  Or something else?

Comment: Actually, looking at your answer, maybe what you mean is "the topology on $X$ is the weak topology generated by $C(X,R)$".  Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

I am still perplexed by this question and I think you are a bit confused about what various words mean and how to use them.  But it looks like the question you were trying to ask is:

> Let $X$ be a set and let $\tau$ be a compact Hausdorff topology on $X$.  Prove that $\tau$ coincides with the weak topology on $X$ induced by the set of all $\tau$-continuous functions $X \to \mathbb{R}$.

If this is the correct interpretation of your question, then we can use the universal mapping property of the weak topology: the weak topology on $X$ induced by $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ is the unique topology with the property that a function $g \colon Z \to X$ (where $Z$ is any topological space) is continuous if and only if $f \circ g \colon Z \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous for every $f \in C(X,\mathbb{R})$.  By uniqueness, we simply need to show that the original topology $\tau$ has this property.

If $g \colon Z \to X$ is continous then $f \circ g \colon Z \to \mathbb{R}$ is clearly $\tau$-continuous for any $\tau$-continuous function $f \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$.  Conversely, suppose $f \circ g \colon Z \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous for every $\tau$-continuous function $f$; we want to prove that $g$ is $\tau$-continuous.

Let $z \in Z$ be any point and let $U \subseteq X$ be a neighborhood of $g(z)$. By Urysohn's lemma there is a $\tau$-continuous function $f \colon X \to [0,1]$ such that $f(g(z)) = 0$ and $f(x) = 1$ for every $x \in X - U$, so that $f^{-1}([0,1)) \subseteq U$.  But then

$$g^{-1}(U) \supseteq g^{-1}(f^{-1}([0,1))) = (f \circ g)^{-1}([0,1))$$

and this is a neighborhood of $z$ since $f \circ g$ is by assumption continuous.

So we have shown that $g^{-1}(U)$ contains a neighborhood of $z$ for every $\tau$-neighborhood $U$ of $g(z)$, meaning $g$ is $\tau$-continuous at $z$. Since $z$ was arbitrary, $g$ is $\tau$-continuous.

Comment: Yeah actually I have a bit confusion of understanding the question thats why I have mentioned the name of the book " introduction to topology by Simmons. Complete regular spaces and normal spaces P no 134. Q no 3". Better if u can see the problem from there.

Comment: "... so that $f^{-1}([0, 1)) = U$." How? All we can say is that $f^{-1}([0, 1))\subseteq U$.

Comment: @Atom The range of $f$ is supposed to be $[0,1]$ rather than $[0,\infty)$ as I had originally written; I edited to update.

Comment: @geetha290krm That's fine - the argument shows that $g$ is continuous at $z$, and $z$ was arbitrary, so $g$ is continuous. It's OK that different $f$'s are used to prove continuity locally at different $z$'s.

Comment: Still, I don't see how $f^{-1}([0, 1))\supseteq U$. There can be points in $U$ which get mapped to $1$: It is only ensured that points outside $U$ are mapped to $1$ and nothing is said about the points in $U$ (except $g(z)$).

Comment: @Atom Oh, well that inclusion isn't needed in the argument - I updated to clarify.

Comment: Yep, that fixes it. I have modified my post to reflect the fact that I no longer believe that your answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have got 1 answer let C(X,R) be set of all functions by which weak topology is generated. Now C(X,R) separates points, so X is hausdorff & by completely regularity I have compactness.

Comment: What do you mean when you write "so $X$ is compact & by complete regularity I have compactness".  As written, it looks like you are using compactness to deduce compactness, which is a little strange.

Comment: I have made some typo. Is it ok now? Please check guy-in-seoul

Comment: I'm not still not sure what the logic is.  It seems that you have two topologies on $X$: the original compact Hausdorff topology, and the weak topology induced on $X$ by $C(X,R)$.  You want to show that they are the same.  It might make your answer more readable if you say which of these two topologies you're talking about.  E.g. when you write "so $X$ is hausdorff ...", do you mean in the original topology (which was an assumption!) or in the weak topology (in which case I don't see that you've proved it).

Comment: I have proved the topo sp is compact & hausdorff assuming the topology generated by C(X,R) separates point & the space is completely regular. If the question is not clear to you then u can see Simmons what I have mentioned in the comments.

Comment: If you take $X$ to be any metric space, then $C(X, R)$ separates points, and any metric space is completely regular.   But not all metric spaces are compact.  So I don't really understand your claim/argument.  In any case, I probably won't comment any more here.  I've pointed out some things I don't understand, and made some suggestions for how to clarify what you've written.  Whether or not you take them into account is entirely up to you.