# The topology of a compact Hausdorff space $X$ is precisely the weak topology due to $C(X)$. How?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness

This question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/921467/673223), <s>but the (upvoted) answer doesn't seem to be correct (see my comment below)</s>. Hence I re-ask the question:

> If $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space, then is its topology precisely the weak topology induced by $C(X)$ (the set of continuous functions $X\to\mathbb K$ where $\mathbb K$ is $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$)?

Let's set the notation: Keep denoting the original space by $X$, whereas use $X_w$ for the weak topology. It's easy to see that $X$ is finer than $X_w$. Conversely, let $U$ be open in $X$. Now by Urysohn ($X$ is normal), we have a continuous function $f\colon X\to [0, 1]$ such that $f$ is $0$ on $X\setminus U$. If I had that $f$ is $0$ precisely on $X\setminus U$, then I'd be done, for then $U$ would be the inverse image of closed $\{0\}$ under $\iota\circ f\colon X\to\mathbb C$ ($\iota$ is the inclusion $[0, 1]\hookrightarrow\mathbb C$) which being continuous means that it's also continuous on $X_w\to\mathbb C$.

But $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ can be larger than $X\setminus U$, right? How to rectify the situation?

Comment: The upvoted answer in the link seems to be wrong. The function $f$ constructed there depends on $z$ but the answerer pretends that the same function works for every $z$ (at least the way I see it).

Answer (score 0):

I talked with my advisor, and he sorted this out:

Let $U$ be open in $X$. W.l.o.g., let $U\subsetneq X$. Let $x\in X$. It suffices to produce a set open $V_w$ in $X_w$, such that $x\in V_w\subseteq U$. By Urysohn (since $X$ is normal), there exists a continuous function $f\colon X\to\mathbb K$ such that $f(x) = 0$ and $f(X\setminus U) = \{1\}$. Now, $V := f^{-1}(B_{1/2}(0))$ does the job since $f\colon X_w\to \mathbb K$ is continuous.

Comment: A similar answer is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4554247/833796. You can also proceed by showing that $X_w$ is Hausdorff (follows from Urysohn's lemma) and the identity map $X\to X_w$ is a continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space, hence a homeomorphim.

Comment: @redwhisker That is a nice alternative!